# How to scan multiple URLs with proxy on Python 2.7?

Tags: python-2.7

How can I scan multiple URLs with proxy using Python and print the result ?

With this script just can scan 1 URL. I mean I can add the code like this:

```
a = s.get('url')
b = s.get('url')
```

but do you guys have simple way to do that ?

```
import requests

proxies = {
    'http': 'http://user:pass@118.97.87.186:8080',
    'https': 'http://user:pass@118.97.87.186:8080',
}

s = requests.Session()
s.proxies = proxies

a = s.get('url')

print(a.text)
```